# How to reduce space between end of table and footnote using parnote

Tags: footnotes, tabularx, parnotes

I have the following table---constructed with tabularx---on which I need to have some footer information. I have the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}   %multiple rows in tables
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
{
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\hsize=.66\hsize}X >{\hsize=.66\hsize}X >{\hsize=.66\hsize}X } %{X L llll>{\hsize=.45\hsize}X >{\hsize=.45\hsize}X}
    \caption{Performance of some weird studies} 
    \hline
    Approach & data1 & data2 & data3 \\
    \hline
    Method1 &                       &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &  \numrange{02}{03}\\
    Method2 &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \num{1} and \num{2}\\
    Method3 &                       &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \num{1} \\
    Method4 &                       &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \num{1} \\ 
    Method5 &                       &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \num{1} \\
    Method6 & \SIlist{20;30}{\percent}  & \SIlist{20;30}{\percent} & \numrange{02}{03} \\
    Method7 & \SI{66.8}{\percent}   & \SI{20}{\percent} & \numrange{02}{03}\parnote[a]{data about 1. \label{ch11:note1}}\parnote[b]{data about 2}  \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{Method8}    & \SIlist{20;30}{\percent}  & \SIlist{20;30}{\percent} & \numrange{02}{03} \\
    &   \SI{20}{\percent}   &   \SI{20}{\percent}   & \numrange{02}{03} \parnotemark{\ref{ch11:note1}} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
%\vskip -2em
\parnotes
}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the space between lower limit of table and start of footnote, I have tried:

```
\renewcommand{\parnotevskip}{-1em}
```

and

```
\vskip and \vspace
```

With not good results where for example using \vskip will ignore all negative values I input, unless the value is too big and pushes the footnote inside the table.

Does anyone has any idea or solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N.B. there must be a `\\` after the `\caption{...}` otherwise it will not compile.

For me the following works:

```
\vspace{-4ex}
```

before the

```
\parnotes
```

Please note that `em` is preferably used in horizontal measurements and `ex` in vertical measurements.

Comment: This works on the MWE, however, when I try on my thesis, which calls other tex files using \include{}. When including a couple of tex files the effect of \vspace{-4ex} fails to work. Currently cannot find why that happens with these two texfiles. Will have to check further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before `table` environment:

```
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}  % Or the distance you want.
```